# Why might System.Random.Sample throw IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm calling `Next()` on a .NET `System.Random` instance inside Unity (2017.1.1f1). It's throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` from inside the protected function [Sample()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.sample?view=netframework-4.7.2), which accepts no arguments and returns a double between 0 and 1.  What might cause this behavior?

Here is the exception in detail

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>
> at System.Random.Sample () [0x0003e] in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Random.cs:91
>
> at System.Random.Next (Int32 maxValue) [0x00017] in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Random.cs:112
>
> at Quicksilver.SysIRand.RandInt (Int32 max_exclusive) [0x00008] in
>   F:\SVNHome\gemrush\GemRush\Assets\Source\Shared\Utility\IRand.cs:38
>
> at Quicksilver.IEnumerableExt.SelectRandom[Skill] (IEnumerable`1
>   collection, IRand rand, Int32 count) [0x00070] in
>   F:\SVNHome\gemrush\GemRush\Assets\Source\Shared\Utility\IEnumerableExt.cs:61

(there's another 13 layers of callstack above this)

This is a multi-threaded environment, but each thread has its own dedicated instance of System.Random.  As you can see from the code below the parameter passed to Next() must have been 1 or higher.

This error was thrown about 1 hour into a complex automated test script, so running multiple times to test theories is expensive, and any modifications that change how the RNG gets invoked will prevent a reproduction.  (If the error somehow involves unintended interaction between threads, then it probably won't be reproducible at all.)

Since it made it an hour into the test script, the overwhelming majority of invocations of this method must NOT be throwing an error.

The function making direct use of the random numbers is here:

```
    // Chooses count items at random from the enumeration and returns them in an array
    // The order of selected items within the array is also random
    // If the collection is smaller than count, the entire collection is returned (in random order)
    public static T[] SelectRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IRand rand, int count = 1)
    {
        if (count <= 0) return new T[0];    // Optimization for trivial case

        T[] keep = new T[count];
        int found = 0;
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            if (found < count)
            {
                // Take the first #count items, in case that's all there are

                // Move a random item of those found so far (including the new one)
                // to the end of the array, and insert the new one in its place
                int r = rand.RandInt(found + 1);
                keep[found++] = keep[r];
                keep[r] = item;
            }
            else
            {
                // Random chance to replace one of our previously-selected elements
                ++found;
                if (rand.RandInt(found) < count)    // probability desired/found
                {
                    // Replace a random previously-selected element
                    int r = rand.RandInt(count);
                    keep[r] = item;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found < count)
        {
            // The collection was too small to get everything requested;
            // Make a new, smaller array containing everything in the collection
            T[] all = new T[found];
            Array.Copy(keep, all, found);
            return all;
        }
        return keep;
    }
```

The error is being thrown from this line:

```
                if (rand.RandInt(found) < count)    // probability desired/found
```

IRand is the interface for a very thin wrapper around System.Random; IRand.RandInt() simply returns Random.Next().

EDIT

Here's how the Random instances are created and distributed:

```
   private void Start()
    {
        SysIRand[] rngs = new SysIRand[parallelTesters];
        if (parallelTesters > 0) rngs[0] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(548913));
        if (parallelTesters > 1) rngs[1] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(138498));
        if (parallelTesters > 2) rngs[2] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(976336));
        if (parallelTesters > 3) rngs[3] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(793461));
        if (parallelTesters > 4) rngs[4] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(648791));
        if (parallelTesters > 5) rngs[5] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(348916));
        if (parallelTesters > 6) rngs[6] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(8467168));
        if (parallelTesters > 7) rngs[7] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(6183569));
        for (int i = 8; i < parallelTesters; ++i)
        {
            rngs[i] = new SysIRand(new System.Random(7 * i * i + 8961 * i + 129786));
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < parallelTesters; ++t)
        {
            SysIRand rand = rngs[t];

            IBot bot = BotFactory.DrawBot(rand);

            BotTester tester = new BotTester(rand, bot);
            tester.testerID = t + 1;
            tester.OnMessage += (str) => UponMessage(tester.testerID + " ~ " + str);
            tester.OnError += (str) => UponError(tester.testerID + " ~ " + str);
            tester.OnGameAborted += UponGameAborted;
            tester.OnDebugMoment += UponDebugMoment;

            testers.Add(tester);
        }
```

(in this run, `parallelTesters` had a value of 3)

Each `BotTester` exclusively uses the Random instance passed to its constructor.  Each thread is private to a single `BotTester`, started from `BotTester.RunGame()`:

```
    public bool RunGame(GameMode mode, int maxGames = 1, long maxMilliSeconds = 100000000, int maxRetries = 5000)
    {
        if (threadRunning) return false;
        thread = new Thread(() => ThreadedRunGame(mode, maxGames, maxMilliSeconds, maxRetries));
        thread.Start();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If value of found is `negative` then you will get this exception. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_

Comment: @PM. if `found` is `negative` it will throw [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2), it's not the same as [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Ahh, yes @IronGeek.

Comment: Did you check the value of `found` when you get this exception?

Comment: It sounds exactly like a `Random` being accessed from multiple threads, so whatever you've done that makes you think that each thread has it's own `Random` instances probably isn't working how you think. But you've not shown us that code.

Comment: @PM Notice that `found` is initialized to 0 and only modified by ++

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation that makes sense is that you think you are accessing `Random()` instance thread safe, with your own words, each thread has its own `Random()` instance but looks like you are accessing the same `Random()` instance while it is still in the middle of calculating. Here is the implementation in Unity. `Sample()` simply calls `InternalSample()`

```
private int InternalSample()
{
  int inext = this.inext;
  int inextp = this.inextp;
  int index1;
  if ((index1 = inext + 1) >= 56)
    index1 = 1;
  int index2;
  if ((index2 = inextp + 1) >= 56)
    index2 = 1;
  int num = this.SeedArray[index1] - this.SeedArray[index2];
  if (num < 0)
    num += int.MaxValue;
  this.SeedArray[index1] = num;
  this.inext = index1;
  this.inextp = index2;
  return num;
}
```

As you can see the places you can get a `IndexOutOfRangeException` are limited,i.e when you access `this.SeedArray`. Here is the definition for SeedArray.

```
public class Random
{
    private int[] SeedArray = new int[56];
....
}
```

It is already allocated to 56 elements and in the implementation of `InternalSample` method you can see that for each call `index1` and `index2` are always limited to be at most `55` unless `InternalSample` method is called multiple times.

Comment: How would threads cause index1/2 to have values above 55?  As local variables, wouldn't each thread have its own copies?

Comment: Please note that private fields inext and inextp values are read into that of index1 and index2. Moreover, same fields are written  back to at the end of the method. If you have a look at the if statements, you can easily notice how any of those values can be set to greater than 55, in the event of multiple accesses.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow.  All variables in the `if` are local (inext and inextp are copied to locals at the start of the function).  Even if they weren't, index1/2 is being set to the same value used in the comparison >= 56.  I can see how threading might change the return value, but not how it causes an index out of bounds.  (I've asked 2 coworkers and neither of them follow you, either.)

Comment: @JeremyLennert, I stand corrected, looking at the source in depth, It does not seem like it will cause an`IndexOutOfRangeException` but rather you will get consistently zero (0) as output, no matter how many times you call `Next()`.

Comment: So I guess that leaves us with zero working theories regarding the origin of the `IndexOutOfRangeException` that I actually got.

Comment: @JeremyLennert, yes unfortunately so! what i can suggest is that you should check the implementation in Unity 2017.1.1f1 then repeat a simple version of your test maybe with more logging then ask on the Unity forum. People who actually work on Unity answers as well